# determining the optimal buffer size for file read in linux

Tags: linux, performance, unix, filesystems, system-calls

I am writing a C program which reads from stdin and writes to stdout. But it buffers the data so that a write is performed only after it reads a specific number of bytes(=SIZE)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main()
{
        char buf[SIZE];
        int n=0;
        //printf("Block size = %d\n", BUFSIZ);

        while( ( n = read(0, buf, sizeof(buf)) ) > 0 )
                write(1, buf, n);
        exit(0);
}
```

Iam running this program on a Ubuntu 18.04 hosted on Oracle Virtual Box(4GB RAM, 2 cores), and testing the program for different values of buffer size. I have redirected the standard input to come from a file(which contains random numbers created dynamically) and standard output to go to /dev/null. Here is the shell script used to run the test:

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 - step size  (bytes)
# $2 - start size (bytes)
# $3 - stop size (bytes)

echo "Changing buffer size from $2 to $3 in steps of $1, and measuring time for copying."

buff_size=$2

echo "Test Data" >testData
echo "Step Size:(doubles from previous size) Start Size:$2 Stop Size:$3" >>testData

while [ $buff_size -le $3 ]
do
        echo "" >>testData
        echo -n "$buff_size," >>testData
        gcc -DSIZE=$buff_size copy.c    # Compile the program for cat, with new buffer size
        dd bs=1000 count=1000000 </dev/urandom >testFile        #Create testFile with random data of 1GB        
        (/usr/bin/time -f "\t%U, \t%S," ./a.out <testFile 1>/dev/null) 2>>testData
        buff_size=$(($buff_size * 2))
        rm -f a.out
        rm -f testFile
done
```

I am measuring the time taken to execute the program and tabulate it. A test run produces the following data:

```
Test Data
Step Size:(doubles from previous size) Start Size:1 Stop Size:524288

1,      5.94,   17.81,

2,      5.53,   18.37,

4,      5.35,   18.37,

8,      5.58,   18.78,

16,     5.45,   18.96,

32,     5.96,   19.81,

64,     5.60,   18.64,

128,    5.62,   17.94,

256,    5.37,   18.33,

512,    5.70,   18.45,

1024,   5.43,   17.45,

2048,   5.22,   17.95,

4096,   5.57,   18.14,

8192,   5.88,   17.39,

16384,  5.39,   18.64,

32768,  5.27,   17.78,

65536,  5.22,   17.77,

131072, 5.52,   17.70,

262144, 5.60,   17.40,

524288, 5.96,   17.99,
```

I dont see any significant variation in user+system time as we use a different block size. But theoretically, as the block size becomes smaller, many number of system calls are generated for the same file size, and it should take more time to execute. I have seen test results in the book 'Advanced Programming in Unix Environment' by Richard Stevens for a similar test, which shows that user+system time reduces significantly if the buffer size used in copy is close to block size.(In my case, block size is 4096 bytes on an ext4 partition)

Why am i not able to reproduce these results? Am i missing some factors in these tests?

Comment: Thank you  @Alfe . As you mentioned earlier, the problem was that the default value of SIZE was not getting overwritten when i pass the parameter through compiler. Commenting out #define SIZE 100 helped. And the observations are similar to what stevens obtained. The time taken for reading from file reduces drastically as we aproach the block size of 4096 and beyond.

Comment: (I migrated my comments into a proper answer.)

Comment: could you post an answer (or update the question) with the updated results. this is a common use case and having this data available would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not disable the line `#define SIZE 100` in your source code so the definition via option (`-DSIZE=1000`) does have influence only above this `#define`.  On my compiler I get a warning for this (`<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition`) at compile time.

If you comment out the `#define` you should be able to fix this error.

Another aspect which comes to mind:

If you create a file on a machine and read it right away after that, it will be in the OS's disk cache (which is large enough to store all of this file), so the actual disk block size won't have much of an influence here.

Stevens's book was written in 1992 when RAM was way more expensive than today, so maybe some information in there is outdated.  I also doubt that newer editions of the book have taken things like these out because in general they are still true.

Comment: By applying the changes you mentioned above, iam able to observe the change in execution time(user+sys time) with respect to buffer size. The data confirms the fact that this is a general truth. Although the RAM is large enough to hold the file i have created(My experimental machine has 4GB of RAM, and iam creating 1GB file for testing), i dont think a large portion of it is reserved for the buffer cache. That may be the reason for why iam able to still observe this characteristics.